# I was programming in pig, i'll loaded the below dataset

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

This is my dataset 
Brand Name followed by price in $symbol

```
Apple iPhone 6s Plus 16GB Space Gray T-Mobile Smartphone 2 cases + Box: 
Iphone 6s 16gb rose gold factory unlocked:$280
iPhone 6s 64gb T-Mobile:$350
Iphone 6S Plus 64 GB Space Gray Sprint International Unlocked:$385
iPhone 6s plus 64gb unlocked.:$600
```

when I load this data using this command:

```
grunt> scrap1 = LOAD '/user/vickysmartboy15/hadoop-test1/scrap.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('([^\\:]+):([^\\:])') as (Name:chararray, price:chararray);
```

after viewing data using: dump operator

my result like this

```
(Apple iPhone 6s Plus 16GB Space Gray T-Mobile Smartphone 2 cases + Box,$)

(Iphone 6s 16gb rose gold factory unlocked,$)

(iPhone 6s 64gb T-Mobile,$)

(Iphone 6S Plus 64 GB Space Gray Sprint International Unlocked,$)

(BRAND NEW Apple iPhone 6S 32Gb Silver Verizon UNLOCKED Clean ESN,$)

(iPhone 6s plus 64gb unlocked.,$)
```

Only `$` is displayed without the number.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What error occured?

Comment: Sry for the previous question,this is the thing actually happens..

Comment: In the first row, there is nothing after `:`. No price. Please update the question with correct data. Also, instead of using RegEx loader, use `PigStorage(':')` and you should be fine.

Comment: $ sign is used as parameter substitution character.You need to fix the input or handle escaping '$' in your pig script.

Comment: Thanks for helping,but i dont know ,how to handle escaping $ in pig script.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrap1 = LOAD '/var/opt/teradata/home/fsbappdev/ashish/scrap.txt' using PigStorage(':') AS (Name:chararray, price:chararray);
```

dump scrap1 will give you below data,i hope this is as expected.

`(Apple iPhone 6s Plus 16GB Space Gray T-Mobile Smartphone 2 cases + Box, )`

`(Iphone 6s 16gb rose gold factory unlocked,$280)`

`(iPhone 6s 64gb T-Mobile,$350)`

`(Iphone 6S Plus 64 GB Space Gray Sprint International Unlocked,$385)`

`(iPhone 6s plus 64gb unlocked.,$600)`

If you want to remove $ sign you can use next relation like

```
scrap2 = foreach scrap1 generate Name, REPLACE(price,'\\\$','')
```

Comment: Thanks this one is helpful. But i just want to filter the price level just like maximum price,min price average etc. i can't do the calculations this one datatype is chararray. so i use the following method for CONVERT CHARARRAY TO INT.

Comment: grunt> scrap2 = foreach scrap generate Name, REPLACE(price,'\\\$','');
grunt> tab = FOREACH scrap GENERATE $0 as name:chararray, $1 as prices:int;
grunt> fil = FILTER tab BY ( prices == 450);
grunt> dump fil;   but i got some error ///]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: sry In my FOREACH query that one is scrap2 not a scrap(mistyped)